# Run script within a specific subnet

Tags: windows, batch-file, network-programming

Can anyone assist with creating a script that will execute within a specific subnet only?

The script should execute the below if the workstations falls within `172.16.10.0` subnet:

```
route delete 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 172.16.10.1
```

Comment: In a normal network, at least all the ones I have ever worked on, the computers are registered in specific groups or Organization Unit containers, whether that be in Windows AD or Novell NDS.  That way you can assign policies to those groups or containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Matt Williamson script and works great. See below:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig^|find "172.16.10."') do (
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%b in ('echo %%a') do ( 
    if "%%b.%%c"==" 172.16" (route delete 192.168.1.0) else echo no match. exiting&exit /b 1
)
)
```